Ubuntu 22.04 stuck on discovering DHCP
My regular Ubuntu 22.04 laptop is not able to discover DHCP in my home wlan since this morning for some reason. We had issues regarding rogue DHCP Servers in the past, but this time the behaviour is different. I just can't resolve any site.
I checked ifconfig:
wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        [REDACTED]  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 [REDACTED]  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 [REDACTED]  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether [REDACTED]  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 693677  bytes 942936693 (942.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1146  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 142638  bytes 21497503 (21.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


I checked via Wireguard and noticed that my computer seems to be stuck on the DHCP discovery as it just constantly tries to discover:
Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (Discover)
    Message type: Boot Request (1)
    Hardware type: Ethernet (0x01)
    Hardware address length: 6
    Hops: 0
    Transaction ID: 0x68a2467f
    Seconds elapsed: 0
    Bootp flags: 0x0000 (Unicast)
        0... .... .... .... = Broadcast flag: Unicast
        .000 0000 0000 0000 = Reserved flags: 0x0000
    Client IP address: 0.0.0.0
    Your (client) IP address: 0.0.0.0
    Next server IP address: 0.0.0.0
    Relay agent IP address: 0.0.0.0
    Client MAC address: [REDACTED]
    Client hardware address padding: 00000000000000000000
    Server host name not given
    Boot file name not given
    Magic cookie: DHCP
    Option: (53) DHCP Message Type (Discover)
        Length: 1
        DHCP: Discover (1)
    Option: (57) Maximum DHCP Message Size
        Length: 2
        Maximum DHCP Message Size: 1500
    Option: (55) Parameter Request List
        Length: 4
        Parameter Request List Item: (1) Subnet Mask
        Parameter Request List Item: (3) Router
        Parameter Request List Item: (28) Broadcast Address
        Parameter Request List Item: (6) Domain Name Server
    Option: (12) Host Name
        Length: 5
        Host Name: wlan0
    Option: (255) End
        Option End: 255
    Padding: 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000…

If I connect to the WLAN via my mobile phone (no issues), open a hotspot and then connect to the hotspot (aka Gateway) via my Laptop, I get DHCP without any issues.
I have now verified that this error happens on multiple devices with this network so it is unlikely that all the devices are damaged. I now think it is either a damaged router or it is a rogue DHCP Server even though I feel like I should be able to see multiple DHCP offers then instead of none.
I am unsure how I can further debug this issue.

I have now verified that there are other devices that have the same issue with this network @John
